# Why core data won't trigger my value transformer?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I'm try to store CCLocation in CoreData.
I'm on beginning of write my custom value transformer, but i'm stuck.

**My transformer:**

```
#import "LocationToDataTransformer.h"
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>
@implementation LocationToDataTransformer
+ (BOOL)allowsReverseTransformation {
    return YES;
}

+ (Class)transformedValueClass {
     NSLog(@"tranform");
    return [NSData class];

}

- (id)transformedValue:(id)value {
    NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:value];
    NSLog(@"tranform");
    return data;
}

- (id)reverseTransformedValue:(id)value {
     CLLocation *location = (CLLocation*)[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:value];
     NSLog(@"tranform");
    return location;
}

@end
```

**And transformer registration:**

```
+ (void)initialize {

        LocationToDataTransformer *transformer = [[LocationToDataTransformer alloc] init];
         [NSValueTransformer setValueTransformer:transformer forName:@"LocationToDataTransformer"];

}
```

I've check [NSValueTransformer valueTransformerNames] array and i see my transformer name in it.

In model I have a entity with 3 attributes:

1. title (string)
2. subtitle (string)
3. location (transformable) - value transformer
   name:LocationToDataTransformer

And when I'm saving my location, nothing happens, other attributes of entity (strings) saves, but location is nil.

**Saving entity code:**

```
-(void)saveBookmark:(BookmarkEntity*)bookmark {
    NSManagedObject *object = [[NSManagedObject alloc]initWithEntity:_descr insertIntoManagedObjectContext:_context];
    BookmarkEntity* entity = (BookmarkEntity*)object;
    entity.title = bookmark.title;
    entity.subtitle = bookmark.subtitle;
    entity.location = bookmark.location;
    if (_context.hasChanges) {
        NSError* error;
        bool saved = [_context save:&error];
        if (!saved) {
            NSLog(@"Error while saving: %@",error.localizedDescription);
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see i've added NSLog's to my transformer, but i not see it in logs. Also i try breakpoints, and no one method from my transformer don't calls.
I even try to set transformer name to "abracadabra" and see nothing in logs, nothing about wrong value transformer name.
I'm totally confused. Anyone have an idea where i missed up? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your transformer is the wrong way around.